# is there any way to make player give specific items when in the coords?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm making my custom plugin and I want to make one thing:

when a player is in a specified region/coords like from 0, 60, 0 to 50, 80, 50 set players inventory clear

Comment: When he enter in and when in leave it or just when he is in ?

Comment: yes when he enters in

Comment: ok let me do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globally, you have to check if it was not in before move, and if it will be in just after.

You can do like that:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) { // when move
    if(e.isCancelled())
        return;
    
    if(!isLocIn(e.getFrom()) && isLocIn(e.getTo())) { // if was not in but will be in
        e.getPlayer().getInventory().clear(); // clear inventory
    }
}

private boolean isLocIn(Location loc) {
    // enter min & max values
    int minX = 0, minY = 60, minZ = 0;
    int maxX = 50, maxY = 80, maxZ = 50;
    
    // get content from given loc
    double x = loc.getX();
    double y = loc.getY();
    double z = loc.getZ();
    
    return x > minX && x < maxX && y > minY && y < maxY && z > minZ && z < maxZ; // check in x/y/z are more than min and lower than max
}
```